# How to map cd/m2 with Android screen brightness

Tags: android, android-source, screen-brightness

The Android Official documentation defines SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS range as 0-255.
How can I map it with cd/m2 (candela/meter square) ?

I need to make between 200 cd/m2 to 400 cd/m2 with 50 as interval.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot map it directly. You will need to have a graph b/w CALDAC parameter (calibration dacs) and luminance (candela/meter squares) also you would need a method to actually check luminance programatically later.
You will have to calculate the caldac parameters for atleast some thresholds - like after each 50 cd/m2.

This all , ofcourse is possible only if you have access to the display firmware and the hardware.